# Exception (anything) in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner on rails application in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

Very hard problem to fix, at least for me (knowing rails since not very long). And as I found the solution I'll share it, so other won't loose as much time as I did :)

Running my rails application in a production server, after restarting apache and trying to access the application you get the following **error**:

> Passenger encountered the following error:
>
> The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Connection refused
>   - /tmp/passenger.1.0.16899/generation-0/spawn-server/socket.16909.15268580
>
> Exception class:
>       PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner::Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my application files (an helper file in this case) I had this code:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

module MyHelper
   ...
end
```

Which was working well in development with `rails server`, but failed with passenger. The solution is to move the `include` inside the module, like so:

```
module MyHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
   ...
end
```

Which may be obvious for most of you, and which will be obvious for me too from now on :)